# Sorting PaginatedDataTable with dynamic data in Rows AND Columns

Tags: android, sorting, flutter, dynamic, dart

I am using PaginatedDataTable to show my data. The data comes from a json. I can show the data and use the pagination. But the sorting does not work in my code.

I am using [this code](https://gist.github.com/horgag1/c4ce662e62d3a0a7ace0648697651dbe) as reference. The sorting works fine in the reference. but only the rows are dynamic in this code.

I receive my columns and rows dynamically and I don't know how to make the sorting work with dynamic data.

This is my DataGrid where I define PaginatedDataTable :

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:boshloo/Dashboard/ChartInfo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Result {
  List<DataCell> cells;
  List<DataColumn> columns;

  Result({this.cells, this.columns});

  bool selected = false;
}

class ResultsDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  final List<Result> _results;
  ResultsDataSource(this._results);

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Result d), bool ascending) {
    _results.sort((Result a, Result b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Result c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int _selectedCount = 0;

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _results.length) return null;
    final Result result = _results[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
        index: index,
        selected: result.selected,
        onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
          if (result.selected != value) {
            _selectedCount += value ? 1 : -1;
            assert(_selectedCount >= 0);
            result.selected = value;
            notifyListeners();
          }
        },
        cells: result.cells);
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount => _results.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;

  void _selectAll(bool checked) {
    for (Result result in _results) result.selected = checked;
    _selectedCount = checked ? _results.length : 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class DataGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChartInfo chartsInfo;
  ResultsDataSource _resultsDataSource = ResultsDataSource([]);
  bool isLoaded = false;

  DataGrid({Key key, this.chartsInfo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DataGridState createState() => _DataGridState();
}

class _DataGridState extends State<DataGrid> {
  ResultsDataSource _resultsDataSource = ResultsDataSource([]);
  bool isLoaded = false;
  int _rowsPerPage = 10;
  int _sortColumnIndex;
  bool _sortAscending = true;

  void _sort<T>(
      Comparable<T> getField(Result d), int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    _resultsDataSource._sort<T>(getField, ascending);
    setState(() {
      _sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      _sortAscending = ascending;
    });
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    List<Result> results = List();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
      results.add(Result(
        cells: dataRows[i].cells,
      ));
    }
    if (!isLoaded) {
      setState(() {
        _resultsDataSource = ResultsDataSource(results);
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }

  List<DataColumn> dataColumns = List();
  List<DataRow> dataRows = List();
  void _setDataColumnsRows() {
    //print('widget.chartsInfo.gridData = ' + widget.chartsInfo.gridData[0].values.toList()[0].toString());
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.chartsInfo.gridFields.length; i++) {
      dataColumns.add(
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(widget.chartsInfo.gridFields.keys.toList()[i]),
          //numeric: false,
          onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
            _sort<String>((Result d) {

              return widget.chartsInfo.gridFields.keys.toList()[i];
            }, columnIndex, ascending);
          },
        ),
      );
    }
    //print('DataCoumns length = ' + dataColumns.length.toString());

    for (var i = 0; i < widget.chartsInfo.gridData.length; i++) {
      List<DataCell> cells = List();
      //print('DataRow[ ');
      for (var j = 0; j < widget.chartsInfo.gridData[i].length; j++) {
        //print('Cell $j = ' + widget.chartsInfo.gridData[i].values.toList()[j].toString());
        cells.add(DataCell(
            Text(widget.chartsInfo.gridData[i].values.toList()[j].toString())));
      }
      //print('cells length = ' + cells.length.toString());
      dataRows.add(DataRow(cells: cells));
      //print(' ]');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setDataColumnsRows();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
            header: Text(widget.chartsInfo.title),
            rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
            onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) {
              setState(() {
                _rowsPerPage = value;
              });
            },
            sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
            sortAscending: _sortAscending,
            onSelectAll: _resultsDataSource._selectAll,
            columns: dataColumns,
            source: _resultsDataSource),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is Dashboard where I receive json and show DataGrid:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:boshloo/Dashboard/ChartInfo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'BarChart.dart';
import 'DataGrid.dart';
import 'GaugeChart.dart';
import 'LineChart.dart';
import 'PieChart.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  List<ChartInfo> charts = List();
  bool isLoaded = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCharts().then((ch) {
      setState(() {
        charts = ch;
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<List<ChartInfo>> _getCharts() async {
    List<ChartInfo> charts = List();
    String url =
        'http://ls.arian.co.ir:8081/api/1.0/arian/mobiledashboard/dashlet-list/71';
    //print('body = ' + body);

    http.Response response = http.Response('{}', 200);
    response = await http.get(url);
    //print('respons body = ' + response.body);
    try {} catch (e) {
      print('failed' + e.toString());
      return null;
    }

    List<dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      //print('json[i]["domain-title"] = ' + json[i]['domain-title'][0]);
      ChartInfo chart;
      if (json[i]['title'] == 'تست گرید ') {
        chart = ChartInfo(
          title: json[i]['title'],
          type: 'grid',
          domainTitle: json[i]['domain-title'],
          measureTitle: json[i]['measure-title'],
          measures: json[i]['measure'],
          gridFields: json[i]['fields'],
          gridData: json[i]['data'],
        );
      } else {
        chart = ChartInfo(
          title: json[i]['title'],
          type: json[i]['type'],
          domainTitle: json[i]['domain-title'],
          measureTitle: json[i]['measure-title'],
          measures: json[i]['measure'],
        );
      }
      //print('title' + chart.title);
      //print('chart measure = ' + chart.measures.values.toList()[0].toString());

      charts.add(chart);

      //print('measures ' + chart.measures[0][1].toString());
    }
    return charts;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _getChartsWidget() {
      List<Widget> chartList = List();
      for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
        if (charts[i].type == 'bar' || charts[i].type == 'column') {
          //chartList.add(BarChart(chartsInfo: charts[i]));
        } else if (charts[i].type == 'pie') {
          //chartList.add(PieChart(chartsInfo: charts[i],));
        } else if (charts[i].type == 'line') {
          //chartList.add(LineChart(chartsInfo: charts[i]));
        } else if (charts[i].type == 'grid'){
          chartList.add(DataGrid(chartsInfo: charts[i]));
        }
      }
      chartList.add(GaugeChart());
      return chartList;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoaded
          ? Container(
              child: ListView(
                children: _getChartsWidget(),
              ),
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

And [The Json Link](http://ls.arian.co.ir:8081/api/1.0/arian/mobiledashboard/dashlet-list/71), (The Third one in array (index #2) is the data that needs to be shown in table.

"fields" (only the key, value is useless) is my columns and "data" is my rows

(I don't think you will need the json file that I included tho).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the List has dynamic data, it's likely that there'll be recurring properties. To include rows with "empty" values, you can [handle null in List.sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113786). With this approach, rows with null property values is included in the List.