# How to sort List<File> in Dart with null objects at end

Tags: list, sorting, flutter, dart

Starting to take in hand Flutter for a study project, I'm wondering about sorting a list of files.

Indeed, my program has a list of 4 files initialized like this :

```
List<File> imageFiles = List(4);
```

This initialization actually implies that my list is like this : `[null,null,null,null]`.

When the user performs actions, this list can fill up. However, the user can delete a file at any time, which can give us the following situation: `[file A, null, null, file d]`.

My question is, how to sort the list when a deletion arrives in order to have a list where null objects are always last (`[file A, file D, null, null]`).

I've looked at a lot of topics already, but they never concern the DART.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason why there should be 4? Is it a business requirement to have min 0 and max 4 image files?

Comment: Yes, the user mustn't be able to load more than 4 files

Comment: I'd suggest creating a 'value object' that can deal with that. I'll add it to my answer below, just a minute

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can sort the list with `list.sort((a, b) => a == null ? 1 : 0);`

Here's a full example, with `String` instead of `File`, that you can run on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = List(4);
  list[0] = "file1";
  list[3] = "file4";

  print("list before sort: $list"); 
  // list before sort: [file1, null, null, file4]

  list.sort((a, b) => a == null ? 1 : 0);

  print("list after sort: $list"); 
  // list after sort: [file1, file4, null, null]

}
```

If it's a **business requirement** to have a max of 4 files, I would suggest creating a **value object** that can handle with that. 
For example:

```
class ImageList {
  final _images = List<String>();

  void add(String image) {
    if(_images.length < 4) {
      _images.add(image);
    }
  }

  void removeAt(int index) {
    _images.removeAt(index);
  }

  String get(int index) {
    return _images[index];
  }

  List getAll() {
    return _images;
  }
}
```

And you could run it like this:

```
void main() {
  ImageList imageList = ImageList();
  imageList.add("file1");
  imageList.add("file2");
  imageList.add("file3");
  imageList.add("file4");
  imageList.add("file5"); // won't be add

  print("imagelist: ${imageList.getAll()}");
  // imagelist: [file1, file2, file3, file4]

  imageList.removeAt(2); // remove file3
  print("imagelist: ${imageList.getAll()}");
  // imagelist: [file1, file2, file4]
}
```

This will make it easier to have control. (This example was again with `String` instead of `File`)

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly, thank you for your quick and precious answer !

Comment: Thanks for the editing and the further informations and help !

Answer (score 8):

You can try this: [Demo (Dartpad)](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3d9f72b4d7b20bd51f97fff179865fa6)

This place all null at end.

```
sortedList.sort((a, b) {
  int result;
  if (a == null) {
    result = 1;
  } else if (b == null) {
    result = -1;
  } else {
    // Ascending Order
    result = a.compareTo(b);
  }
  return result;
})
```

You can play with this another demo too: [Demo 2 - Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=65b50f4fa9cc2d8c45f115fa337ae73f)

Comment: If you want the null values at the beginning, simply reverse the `result = 1` and `result = -1` lines.

Comment: This flips the null values back and forward if you use it multiple times. You need to add "if(a == null && b == null) { result = 0 } else if ..." ad the beginning.

Comment: @Steffomio you can test it multiple times here without issue: https://dartpad.dev/?id=6bce751e7ace6ac7064897e7df8fcbb6

Comment: @Jorge Thanks, however for some unknown reason I needed it in my code to fix the flip-flop effect. So if you ever stumble over such behavior, thats a quick&dirty fix.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I made an extension function of Jorge's answer.

```
extension ListExtension<E> on List<E> {
  void sortByNullable<K extends Comparable<K>>(K? Function(E element) keyOf) {
    sortByCompare((element) => keyOf(element), (a, b) {
      if (a == null) {
        return 1;
      } else if (b == null) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return a.compareTo(b);
      }
    });
  }
}
```